# Why do I get AttributeError: 'Variable' object has no attribute '__dict__' when using pickle.loads?

Tags: python, pickle

Here is the error I get. The path to my pickle file exists, and my coworker is able to get this working on their computer with the exact same code. We are both running python 3.7, and have macbooks.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d41a2931d19e> in <module>
     1 pickle_file = '/path/to/file/pickle_filename.p'
----> 2 pickle_contents = pickle.load(open(pickle_file,"rb"))
     3 print(pickle_contents)
AttributeError: 'Variable' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

Comment: Are you able to provide an example that produces such a pickle file so we can play around with it on our machines? If the pickle file contains complicated structures/classes, then you should also make sure you and your coworker have the same version of any libraries used to define the objects in your pickle file.

Comment: This was the solution- the libraries defined in the pickle file had different versions. Thank you.